# Select rows by id inside string with ids separated by comma

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have to write a mysql query that will fetch rows from  the wp_posts table (of post_type attachment) by id that is inside a string of ids separated by comma inside wp_postmeta.

It may sounds complicated, but it is really simple, here is the example:

If tables have the following data:

```
wp_posts:
ID | post_type
1  | attachment
2  | attachment
3  | attachment
4  | contest
5  | contest

wp_postmeta:
ID | post_id | meta_key      | meta_value
1  | 4       | contest_works | 1,2
1  | 5       | contest_works | 3
```

after running query I would like to get:

```
ID | post_type
1  | attachment
2  | attachment
3  | attachment
```

I came up with the query below but it returns rows of post type contest instead of attachment for some reason.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts work
INNER JOIN wp_posts AS contest ON
  (
    SELECT meta_value 
    FROM wp_postmeta contestmeta 
    WHERE contest.ID = contestmeta.post_id AND contestmeta.meta_key = 'contest_works'
  ) LIKE CONCAT('%', work.ID, '%') AND contest.post_type = 'contest'
WHERE work.post_type = 'attachment'
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you :)

Comment: I would consider changing your schema to not hold a CSV

Comment: @Dan So do you think that this query is impossible to implement, or it will be really slow with more rows?

Comment: LIKE queries will always go slow once you will get more rows.

Comment: I've created an SQL fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19c9c/3 I seem to be getting the correct stuff?

Comment: @ThomasVdBerge The problems appears to be LIKE, for instance if there is 279,1289,213 it will get attachments for posts 2,7,9,27,29....

Comment: I think you're dealing with a poorly designed WordPress plugin here. Notice that the standard WP api for the postmeta table offers a `$unique` parameter, allowing you to put each value in its own row. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM wp_posts p INNER JOIN
     wp_postmeta pm 
     on pm.meta_key = 'contest_works' and
        find_in_set(p.id, pm.meta_value)
WHERE p.post_type = 'attachment';
```

Storing lists in comma-delimited lists should be highly discouraged.  Alas, this seems like a reasonable data structure in the in the Word Press data model.

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19c9c/4) is a SQL Fiddle.  Also, this will be a pretty slow query as the data scales.  You have a problem storing the list as a field.  The better solution is to store one value per row.

Comment: awesome fiddle and all GL !

Comment: Although this is not exactly the correct query (what about verification that pm belongs to post of type contest) find_in_set solved the problem. Thank you very much !